# how to write a table of contents with jekyll and redcarpet

Tags: jekyll, jekyll-extensions

using jekyll 2.0.3,
I initially configured _config.yml with

```
markdown: kramdown
```

and I was able to add a table of contents as follows, in my example.md:

```
---
layout: page
title: Sample
---
{:toc}

## section 1
## section 2
```

however, I switched to redcarpet, see _config.yml:

```
markdown: redcarpet
redcarpet:
  extensions: ["no_intra_emphasis", "fenced_code_blocks", "autolink", "strikethrough", "superscript", "with_toc_data"]
```

and now `{:toc:}` does not work.

The documentation of redcarpet v2.2.2 (used by jekyll 2.0.3):
https://github.com/vmg/redcarpet/blob/v2.2.2/README.markdown#and-its-like-really-simple-to-use

mentions `:with_toc_data`, but I don't where/how to use this.

how can i display the table of contents using redcarpet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that `:with_toc_data` is an option for an instance of the redcarpet renderer, and not a configuration extension.

Unfortunately, Jekyll doesn't seem to expose this renderer option, so I don't think you'll be able to use it. [The docs say](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/):

> no renderer options aside from `smart` can be specified in Jekyll.

But you can use a table of contents jekyll plugin instead. A quick search returns a number of available options, and [one](https://github.com/dafi/jekyll-toc-generator) is linked from the official Jekyll site.

Comment: thx. i see that github pages (which uses jekyll) does not support external plugins :( i'll use this js instead: https://github.com/ghiculescu/jekyll-table-of-contents

Comment: Keep in mind that you can host any static content on github pages, so if you want to generate the site locally with your custom plugins and then push it up to github it will work

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this should work. Mention this in the **_config.yml** file.

```
markdown: redcarpet
redcarpet:
      extensions: [with_toc_data]
```

I'm using markdown on my blog along with JQuery and a js file. This is how it looks like.

[image]

Here is the detailed guide on how to do it - [Jekyll TOC](http://blog.webjeda.com/jekyll-toc/)